# Black screen after splash screen. How can I display an image when my application launches and remove it later at a certain point?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I want to display an image on the entire screen when the user starts my application because I get a black screen for 2 seconds after my launch screen(launchscreen.storyboard) disappears and until Draw(GameTime gameTime) is executed. The image needs to be displayed until I execute LogoView.RemoveFromSuperview(); and the image needs to be above the images that will get drawn later in void Draw(GameTime gameTime).

Is it possible to use the image from Assets.xcassets-->Image? Will iOS automatically chose the appropriate image size for the current device from Assets.xcassets-->Image?

[Assets.xcassets image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGNkJ.png)

I found the following answer on stackoverflow but I don't know what "View" is.

[iOS Fit Image to Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489864/ios-fit-image-to-screen)

I get an error message in Program.cs if I use "View":

> Error CS0103: The name 'View' does not exist in the current context

How can I display an image when my application launches and remove it later at a certain point in Game1.cs?

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace MyProject
{
[Register("AppDelegate")]
class Program : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    private static Game1 game;
    private UIImageView LogoImage;

    public override void FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LogoImage = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("Launchscreenlogo.png"));
        LogoImage.Tag = 1234;
        LogoImage.Frame = View.Frame;
        View.AddSubview(LogoImage);
        View.BringSubviewToFront(LogoImage);
        RunGame();
    }

    private void G_RemoveLogo(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //remove image
        var LogoView = View.ViewWithTag(1234);
        if (null != LogoView)
            LogoView.RemoveFromSuperview();
    }
}
}
```

Game1.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
public class Game1 : Game
{
private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
public event EventHandler RemoveLogo;

public Game1()
{
    _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
}

protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here

    RemoveLogo?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    // TODO: Add your drawing code here

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
}
}
```

Comment: this is commonly referred to as a "splash screen" and has a standard implementation in iOS.  Is that not what you want?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos

Comment: I have already created a splash screen in launchscreen.storyboard. But I need to set a second image in FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app) as background when the splash screen disappears. I have a black screen after the splash screen disappears and until Draw(GameTime gameTime) is executed. Therefore, I want to set a second image(the same file as I use for the splash screen) as background and I want to remove this image in Game1.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View` belongs to Controller , we can get a current `View` easily in a ViewController ,in `AppDelegate` try to use `Window.RootViewController.View` instead .

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
   LoadApplication(new App());

   LogoImage = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("Launchscreenlogo.png"));
   LogoImage.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;

   Window.RootViewController.View.AddSubview(LogoImage);
   Window.RootViewController.View.BringSubviewToFront(LogoImage);

   return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}

public void G_RemoveLogo()
{
    //remove image
    LogoImage.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

And call the following method to remove the image in Game class.

```
(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).G_RemoveLogo();
```

Comment: I get this error message when I try to remove the image in Game1.cs: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AppDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) How can I use AppDelegate? Which using statement should I use?

Comment: Change it from `AppDelegate` to `MyProject.Program `.